# multiple inner joins adds extra values to count

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am trying to include results from other tables in a [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53718429/calculate-standard-deviation-inside-pivot-table) query using multiple joins below:

```
SELECT mid                             as mID,
   round((x.qty_sum / x.qty_count), 5) as qtAVG,
   round(x.qty_stddev, 5)              as qtSTDDEV,
   x.qty_count                         as qtCOUNT,
   round((x.rel_sum / x.rel_count), 5) as relAVG,
   round(x.rel_stddev, 5)              as relSTDDEV,
   x.rel_count                         as relCOUNT,
FROM (SELECT t.mid,
         SUM( mt = 'qt' )   as qty_count,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t_r.mt = 'qt' THEN rt END)  as qty_sum,
         STD(CASE WHEN t_r.mt = 'qt' THEN rt END)  as qty_stddev,
         SUM( t_r.mt = 'rel' ) as rel_count,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t_r.mt = 'rel' THEN rel END) as rel_sum,
         STD(CASE WHEN t_r.mt = 'rel' THEN rel END) as rel_stddev
  FROM t_r r
right join t_m t on t.mid = r.mid
right join m_k m on m.mid = t.mid
right join k_d k on m.kid = k.kid
  GROUP BY t.mid
 ) x;
```

Using my query above, `qty_count` for `111` when `mt` is `qt` returns `6` instead of `2`. `2 * (count of 111 in table m_k)`

When I remove this portion of the join, I get the desired sum for `qtCOUNT` and `relCOUNT`

```
right join m_k m on m.mid = t.mid
right join k_d k on m.kid = k.kid
```

What am I doing wrong and how may I solve it?

Data:

m_k

```
mid  kid
--------
109  2
110  2
110  4
111  1
111  2
111  3
```

k_d

```
kid  k_desc
-----------
1    desc1
2    desc2
3    desc3
4    desc4
```

m_d

```
mid  col1   col2   col3   col4
-------------------------------
109  val_a  val_d  val_g  val_j
110  val_b  val_e  val_h  val_k
111  val_c  val_f  val_i  val_l
```

t_r

```
mid  rt  stamp                  mt
----------------------------------
111  3   2018-12-08 01:30:31   rel
111  4   2018-12-08 03:41:56   qt
111  3   2018-12-08 02:29:10   qt
110  1   2018-12-08 06:13:51   rel
110  5   2018-12-08 11:44:39   qt
109  1   2018-12-08 10:39:51   rel
```

Other queries that achieve the same as above is fine.

Comment: Probably because of the laravel tag ;-)

Comment: We can't tell what is going on -- What table are `mt` and `mid` in?  Please edit the query to qualify them.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: You gave Data for Table `m_d` (which is not used in your query) and omitted sample Data for Table `t_m` (which you reference in your query).  Without the data for `t_m`, it is difficult to help you; because assumptions must then be made about the missing data since you didn't use mnemonic names for your Tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem by moving

```
right join m_k m on m.mid = t.mid
right join k_d k on m.kid = k.kid
```

outside of the derived table `x`. Final query looks like this:

```
SELECT mid                             as mID,
   round((x.qty_sum / x.qty_count), 5) as qtAVG,
   round(x.qty_stddev, 5)              as qtSTDDEV,
   x.qty_count                         as qtCOUNT,
   round((x.rel_sum / x.rel_count), 5) as relAVG,
   round(x.rel_stddev, 5)              as relSTDDEV,
   x.rel_count                         as relCOUNT,
FROM (SELECT mid,
         SUM( mt = 'qt' )   as qty_count,
         SUM(CASE WHEN mt = 'qt' THEN rt END)  as qty_sum,
         STD(CASE WHEN mt = 'qt' THEN rt END)  as qty_stddev,
         SUM( mt = 'rel' ) as rel_count,
         SUM(CASE WHEN mt = 'rel' THEN rel END) as rel_sum,
         STD(CASE WHEN mt = 'rel' THEN rel END) as rel_stddev
  FROM t_r r
right join t_m t on t.mid = r.mid
  GROUP BY mid
 ) x
right join m_k m on m.mid = x.mid
right join k_d k on k.kid = m.kid
group by m.mid;
```

Comment: The rationale:  All `JOINing` is done _before_ aggregates (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc).  So, be sure to do only the `JOINs` necessary before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Why are you Right-Joining to `m_k` and `k_d`?  You don't use them in your select.  Same things goes for your Group-By of `m.mid` - you are not using any aggregate functions in your Select for this to work.